# ¿Cómo utilizar un tooltip con @Html.CheckboxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

Tengo un proyecto asp.net mvc5 hay un

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(model => model.mi_atributo, new { @class = "form-check-input"})
```

,a el cual quiero ponerle un mensaje cuando se le posicione el puntero encima, enconté esto:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.mi_atributo, new { htmlAttributes = new { Title = "mi mensaje" }, })
```

, y

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { Title = "mi mensaje"  })
```

pero parece que no funciona con CheckboxFor, utilizo la versión 5.2.7.0 de mvc.

Comment: Es correcto, en @Html.PasswordFor me funciona, pero en @Html.CheckboxFor(model => model.mi_atributo, new { htmlAttributes = new { Title = "mi mensaje" } }) no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes poner todos los `htmlAttributes` juntos en un solo objeto anónimo.

Así debe funcionar:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.mi_atributo, new { title = "mi mensaje", @class = "form-check-input"  })
```

Ten en cuenta que la propiedad `mi_atributo` debe ser del tipo `bool` en el Modelo.

Comment: Funciona, gracias.